# jooq oracle stored procedures with ARRAY, Invalid column type: 1111

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jooq

I am trying to call a stored procedure in Oracle using JOOQ. Some of the in and out parameters of the stored procedure are  custom type.

the definition of one of them is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TAB_VARCHAR2_500" is table of varchar2(500);
```

I am creating oracle.sql.ARRAY type in this way:

```
ArrayDescriptor ard=ArrayDescriptor("TAB_VARCHAR2_500",connection);

//this is my object of the stores procedure, generated by jooq

aimws.setPDataDesc(new oracle.sql.ARRAY(ard,connection,lineData.toArray()));

aimws.execute(jooq.configuration());
```

But when I execute, I am getting this (even if I set the values to null):

```
SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type: 1111; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111
```

In the java classes generated by JOOQ for that stored procedure the type is

```
public static final Parameter<Object> P_DATA_DESC = createParameter("P_DATA_DESC", org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDefaultDataType("TABLE"), false);
```

I am using Spring deploying the application as an EAR project in jboss

What I am doing wrong? what kind of object I have to create in java?

Comment: There should be a generated class for `TAB_VARCHAR2_500`. You shouldn't need to wrestle the ojdbc APIs, such as `ArrayDescriptor` and `ARRAY`. Did you perhaps (accidentally) exclude that class from the source code generation? This can happen via `<exclude/>` or if the table type is in a different schema than the table, and you didn't include both schemas.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for your prompt answer. I was using <include> to generate only what I was going to use. Now I have a record class with the definition of that UDT.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for your prompt answer. I was using <include> to generate classes only for what I was going to use. Now I generate java classes for the whole schema and I see a "record" class for that particular type, but not a "table" class. Not sure what java object I have to send. I have the data in a ArrayList<String>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that you have not included the `TAB_VARCHAR2_500` type during code generation, which is why it's missing from the generator output. Once you let the generator generate this type, you can use it as a wrapper for arrays. Typically:

```
aimws.setPDataDesc(new TabVarchar2_500Record(lineData));
aimws.execute(jooq.configuration());
```

Comment: I used that way, but still same error "Invalid column type: 1111". I have the trace level set to debug and I can see the bind values when routine is called, being now as they should be (). How can I get more information about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Solved!! It was what you pointed out the first time. I mix the configuration files. How can include the UDT using only the tag <include>.

Comment: You have to include `TAB_VARCHAR2_500`